# How to decode multiline text in a textnode using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, decode

I have text as below in a textnode in my html: I want to decode the text and show it properly.

```
 "is_community_page": false,
 "likes": 7905,
 "id": "1262424233773457",
 "name": "24HindiNews.com",
 "website": "http://www.24hindinews.com",
 "link": "https://www.facebook.com/24hindinews/",
 "category": "Media/News/Publishing",
 "is_verified": false,
 "cover": {
    "cover_id": "1282615735087640",
    "offset_x": 0,
    "offset_y": 0,
    "source": "https://fbcdn-sphotos-g-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xfa1/v/t1.0-9/s720x720/12249927_1282615735087640_7473328688518215798_n.jpg?oh=fb4c8d0a7156e505ddde8918dcc660c1&oe=56F88371&__gda__=1458328314_8c467f06d703491d9d1d3b0b3efabd3d",
    "id": "1282615735087640"
 },
 "description": "\u0924\u093e\u091c\u093c\u093e \u0916\u092c\u0930\u0947\u0902 24 \u0918\u0902\u091f\u0947 \u0938\u093f\u0930\u094d\u092b www.24HindiNews.com \u092a\u0930 \nThis is official page of www.24HindiNews.com",
 "about": "\u0924\u093e\u091c\u093c\u093e \u0916\u092c\u0930\u0947\u0902 24 \u0918\u0902\u091f\u0947 \u0938\u093f\u0930\u094d\u092b www.24HindiNews.com \u092a\u0930 "
},
{
```

there are some characters like \u0918 etc.

i am trying

```
$("pre")
  .contents()
  .filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === 3 ;//Node.TEXT_NODE
    })
.each(function(){
  krishna = decodeURIComponent(this.data)
  console.log(krishna);
  console.log($(this).html(this.data).text())
  $(this).replaceWith(krishna);

});
```

Comment: How about scanning the values for `\n`? Btw it's json not html. In html you would have to scan for `<br>`, `<p>` etc

Comment: Its a json text in. <pre> json text node </pre>